# When i m using gem 'spree_gift_card' in gem 'spree', '2.3.4' at that time gives error like in rails 4.1.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree, spree-auth-devise

1) I create app using spree and in my gem file code.

```
rails 4.1.6
gem 'spree', '2.3.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-3-stable'
```

gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-3-stable'

2) `bundle install`

3) It works fine.

4) But i need to add extension `gem 'spree_gift_card', github: 'jdutil/spree_gift_card'`

5) `bundle install`

6) gives error  like this,

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_frontend":

```
In Gemfile:
  spree_gift_card (>= 0) ruby depends on
    spree_frontend (~> 2.2.0) ruby

  spree (= 2.3.4) ruby depends on
    spree_frontend (2.3.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices

1. use spree 2.2 - or whatever version the extension last worked with
2. for the extension, alter the gemspec file to use the later spree version, and cross your fingers that the new version didn't break the extension (or fix it if it did)

Comment: Right now i m using
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
and use 

gem 'spree', '2.2.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_gift_card', github: 'jdutil/spree_gift_card'